# How can I fix 'no such table' error with SQLAlchemy and SQLite when accessing 'item' table in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently going through a Python Flask course from Youtube, where we learn about the Flask library from Python. Throughout the course, we also get to deal with databases, where we use flask_sqlalchemy. However, I got stuck at the end of the 6th chapter, where we split our code from a folder and two files, to multiple files and folders. I copied the exact same code from the tutorial, but still resulted with the following error, after navigating to /market on the webpage: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: item
[SQL: SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.name AS item_name, item.price AS item_price, item.barcode AS item_barcode, item.description AS item_description
FROM item]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Everything was done inside a folder named "FlaskMarket", containing a file named `run.py` and a subfolder named `market` .

FlaskMarket/run.py:

```
from market import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

FlaskMarket/market/instance/market.db: Database, containing the 'item' table

FlaskMarket/market/templates/base.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>
        {% block title %}

        {% endblock %}
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Flask Market</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('market_page') }}">Market</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       </div>
     </nav>
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}
      <!-- Future Content here -->


      
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
   <style>
      body {
        background-color: #212121;
        color: white
      }
   </style>
</html>
```

FlaskMarket/market/templates/home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
  Home Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  This is our content for the Home Page
{% endblock %}
```

FlaskMarket/market/templates/market.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
  Market Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- Your Columns HERE -->
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Barcode</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Your rows inside the table HERE: -->
        {% for item in items %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.barcode }}</td>
            <td>${{ item.price }}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-outline btn-info">More Info</button>
              <button class="btn btn-outline btn-success">Purchase this Item</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

FlaskMarket/market/_*init*_.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from market import routes
```

FlaskMarket/market/models.py:

```
from market import db


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Item {self.name}'
```

FlaskMarket/market/routes.py:

```
from market import app
from flask import render_template
from market.models import Item

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
    items = Item.query.all()
    return render_template('market.html', items=items)
```

Also, VsCode keeps generating a folder named __ pychache __ inside FlaskMarket itself, but also extra inside the market folder. The same happens with instance, which contains my database, appearing once in FlaskMarket and again in market...

Comment: If you go into the Flask Shell (`$ flask shell`) and run `db.drop_all()` and `db.create_all()`, does that fix it? Little warning though, `db.drop_all()` will completely drop all data and tables from your db. If you cannot risk data loss, try just `db.create_all()`.

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin, I just entered `db.create_all()` in the Flask Shell and as a result, I was able to relocate to /market on he webpage without encountering any errors. However, this time, an empty table showed up, meaning that there wasn't any data. I suspect, that there's still an issue with the database.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it! Only thing I had to do, was remove `instance` from `market`...